# How are Nested classes different between C# and Java

Tags: java, c#, class, oop

In Java, if a nested class is not declared as static, it cannot be accessed within a static context. This means an instance of the inner class can only be created through an instance of the outer class. For example:

```
class Prac{
  class Inner{} 
  public static void main(){
    Inner myObj = new Prac().new Inner();
  }   
}
```

For my Java-adjusted brain, this makes sense. If an inner class isn't static, it would require an instance of the outer class to be instantiated from. In c# however, I can declare Inner non-statically as a nested class and directly instantiate it from a static context in the Main method.

I read that c# nested classes are like c++ and not java, but I'm not familiar with how inner classes work in any other way. What are the mechanics underlying nested classes in c#?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types)?

Comment: One way to think of nested C# classes is as another (more complicated) way to declare a class inside a namespace. From the perspective of the code using the (nested) class there is no obvious difference between `namespace Prac { public class Inner {} }` and `public class Prac { public class Inner {} }`, because both times you'd do `new Prac.Inner()`. Hence the only real speciality of nested C# classes is that they have access to the parent's class members.

Comment: There is also visibility: nested classes can be declared as `private` or `protected` or whatever, which means only the containing class/derived classes or assembly etc can access it. This is true of both C# and Java I think. And when it comes to generics, C# nested classes inherit the outer's generic types

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Thanks for the reference. I checked it out, and while a bit confused I get some of how it works. In Java, specifying a nested class as static simply means instances of this inner class can be created from a static context, ie simply through the class name of its parent. In C#, setting a class as static means it cannot have any object instances. It simply holds static data. But when it's not static, this nested class simply serves to define some hierarchy of classes, but can always be instantiated statically from inside the containing class. Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that Microsoft strongly suggests to [avoid public nested classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/nested-types?redirectedfrom=MSDN).
The core idea of a nested class is to completely hide to everyone an implementation detail of an abstraction. Consider that example:

**IUserService**

```
public interface IUserService
{
    IEnumerable<string> GetAllUsernames();
}
```

**MockUserServiceProvider**

```
public static class MockUserServiceProvider
{
    // Public
    public static IUserService New() => new MockUserService();



    // Nested Private class
    private class MockUserService : IUserService
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> GetAllUsernames()
        {
            yield return "Bob";
            yield return "Mary";
        }
    }
}
```

The goal of the Mock provider is to make available to the public an instance of the interface to Mock, it does not make sense to bind the provider to a specific class type, indeed, in theory, that type just shouldn't exist at all. So the best one can do (Without use some I.L. magic as Moq does for example) is to completely hide the class definition with a private nested class, so that no one can access it.